# Как грамотно реализовать разграничение многопоточного доступа к ресурсу?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, concurrency

Здравствуйте. Просьба помочь определиться со способом синхронизации потоков, обращающихся к одному буферу данных. Определен класс буфера изображения, который в каждый момент времени предоставляет доступ к пикселям некоторого прямоугольного фрагмента растрового изображения. Упрощенно он имеет следующий интерфейс:

```
template <class Pixel>
class Buffer {
public:
  condition_variable& initialize(HImage<Pixel>* image, const uint threadsCount, const SizeI& bufferWindowSize, function<bool (PointI& point)> getNextWindowPos);

  const RectI currentWindow() const;

  inline const Pixel& pixel(const PointI& pos) const;
  inline void setPixel(const PointI& pos, const Pixel& value);

  void reportWindowProcessed();
};
```

Планируемый сценарий его использования

1. Инициализация: указание изображения, числа потоков, работающих с буфером, размера окна буфера и callback функции, предоставляющей следующее положение окна буфера или возвращающей false, если все необходимые фрагменты изображения обработаны. Функция инициализации возвращает условную переменную, с использованием которой создавший буфер поток будет оповещен о завершении обработки данных буфера.
2. Запуск потоков - обработчиков, осуществляющих чтение / запись пикселей буфера. В цикле выполнения каждый поток

   - получает доступное окно буфера посредством метода currentWindow()обрабатывает некоторые пиксели этого окна (выбор конкретных пикселей осуществляется на основе идентификатора потока)
   - сообщает буферу о завершении работы с данными текущего окна вызовом метода reportWindowProcessed()
   - переходит в состояние ожидания. Из этого состояния поток должен выйти, когда буфер обновит положение окна либо когда создавший буфер поток будет оповещен о окончании обработки и сообщит об этом потоку - обработчику.
3. Завершение. Если при обновлении положения окна буфер в ответ на запрос следующего положения getNextWindowPos() получает false, то он оповещает о завершении работы родительский поток, вызывая метод notify_one() условной переменной, ссылка на которую была возвращена при инициализации и которую ожидает поток-родитель.

Буфер обновляет положение окна в методе reportWindowProcessed() при условии, что накапливаемое число потоков, вызвавших этот метод, совпадает с числом запущенных потоков, т.е. что все потоки закончили работу с окном. В этом случае счетчик потоков сбрасывается и происходит обновление окна.
Неясным для меня моментом остается способ, которым буфер будет выводить потоки из состояния ожидания после обновления окна.
Т.е. в коде потока-обработчика

```
//полезная работа с пикселями текущего окна
...
buffer.reportWindowProcessed();
//как здесь реализовать ожидание обновления состояния буфера?
```

**Обновление**

Более производительным представляется хранить в буфере вектор атомарных флагов для каждого потока. В вызове методе `reportWindowProcessed(const int threaID)` указывать `id` отработавшего потока, а в теле этого метода сбрасывать флаг готовности потока (или напротив устанавливать все флаги, если все потоки обработали текущее окно). Тогда каждый поток будет ожидать

```
while (!buffer.isReady(threadID) || !stop) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
}
```

где `isReady()` возвращает значение флага готовности потока

Comment: Как на счет [делегатов](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/48020/)? При обновлении буфера добавлять делегат, а после обработки убирать его и все по кругу. А на самом деле задумайтесь, может вам **не нужны потоки**, описанный вами алгоритм будет работать только медление при использовании потоков.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, спасибо за ответ. Попробую Ваш вариант. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Не могу согласится с тем, что потоки лишь замедлят работу, можете подробнее пояснить почему? Изображение трансформируется с достаточно сложными вычислениями для каждого пикселя и скорость ограничивается не вводом / выводом растровых данных, а операциями вычисления положения пикселя и  точной интерполяцией

Comment: потоки не гарантируют выполнение на разных ядрах процессора. Правильно ли, что это __Итерационная задача__? Если да, то вот мои мысли:  затраты времени на синхронизацию и передачу данных могут быть не оправданными. Все зависит от конкретной ситуации, но я не эксперт в вашем вопросе, и не знаю алгоритмической сложности ваших вичислений.